# How is the Java bytecode executed in a Java FX self-contained application package?

Tags: java, javafx-2, bytecode, packaging, execution

It is possible to [deploy](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm) self-contained Java applications. But, how is the bytecode executed? Is it interpreted or is it compiled JIT? I could not find proper documentation about this.

Comment: The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javafx) has useful information, have you read it?

Comment: @fge Did you actually read that entry? And does it answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the JRE is embedded within the package, so bytecode would presumably be executed just as it would with a standalone JRE (interpreted mode initially, then JIT compiled based on configured thresholds).

Comment: Yes, since JRE contains a JVM, and Oracle's JVM is HotSpot, I guess you are right (see http://www.javabeat.net/2013/02/what-is-the-difference-between-jrejvm-and-jdk/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot)